# getting the confusion matrix for each cross validation fold

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I'm running a pipeline with logistic regression through cross validation using scikit-learn. I'm getting the scores from each fold in the code below. How do I get the confusion matrix?

```
clf = make_pipeline(MinMaxScaler(), LogisticRegression())
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
```

Answer (score 9):

I think what you want is:

```
clf = make_pipeline(MinMaxScaler(), LogisticRegression())

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
y_pred = cross_val_predict(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=3)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
```

From [3.1.1.2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) of scikit-learn's online documentation:

> The function cross_val_predict has a similar interface to
> cross_val_score, but returns, for each element in the input, the
> prediction that was obtained for that element when it was in the test
> set. Only cross-validation strategies that assign all elements to a
> test set exactly once can be used (otherwise, an exception is raised).
>
> Note that the result of this computation may be slightly different from those obtained using cross_val_score as the elements are grouped in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ Brian O'Donnell